# Visual basic 2015 makes my PC shutdown from power source

Tags: visual-studio, installation, iso

I have downloaded the full (3.7gb) iso visual studio2015 from official site.I was aware that it would take a 'long' time. But the 'acquiring' part of installation got completed in 10 min. The 'applying' part was also progressing fast.I don't know why my PC got turn off from its power source (the switch was turn on but in my CPU it doesn't display that green light which is it displays when it is turn on even it is not started). Even I was not able to turn it on from my CPU button .I have to switch off from power source and then again turn on.
I thought there might be issues with electricity but when I again tried to install visual studio 2015 iso same thing happened again.
Please help me :((

Comment: Maybe contact the Microsoft Support?

Comment: Do you mean your desktop or laptop auto turn off during the VS installation? If it is turn off, how did you check the switch in your CPU? What’s the green light stands for?

Comment: My CPU has a green light(led) at its back.it always glow unless I switch off my CPU directly from power source(not just simple shut down(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in such a condition few months back and later found that  it was  an issue of overload and overheating with the pc.Make sure that you have appropriate environment and conditions as well as the location of the CPU.You can even try to open the CPU cabinet and check whether there is ventilation facility available because during the setup of visual studio the CPU may acquire a huge workload on it processor and RAM which may the cause the overheating of the processor leading  to the shutting down of pc for protection from further damage